# Add overlapping days covered with different ID types in SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata, overlap, date-range

I currently have data that looks like this:

```
    Member | ID | Date_Begin | Date_End | Days_Covered
    ------------------------------------------------
    1      | A  | 1/1/15     | 1/31/15  | 30
    1      | A  | 1/1/15     | 1/31/15  | 30
    1      | A  | 2/1/15     | 2/28/15  | 27
    1      | B  | 1/15/15    | 2/15/15  | 31
    1      | B  | 4/1/15     | 4/30/15  | 29
```

The output would be:

```
    Member | ID | Day_Covered
    -------------------------
    1      | A  | 87
    1      | B  | 29
```

A's can be grouped together, and B's can be grouped together. But if A or B (or C...) overlap, then it only counts once for either A or B, not twice. If A overlaps with A, it counts twice (and B that overlaps B would count twice, etc.).

How could you code something in SQL to get this sort of output given the data above?

Comment: The three ID A's effectively span 1/1/15 to 3/29/15. Since B overlaps with A during this time, it does not count. Also, I realized there was an error in the output of B and I've updated the example to reflect. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use some variant of this, assuming you're able to use sys_calendar.

```
select
    tbl.member,
    tbl.id,
    count(*) as day_covered
from
    tbl
    inner join sys_calendar.calendar as cal
        on cal.calendar_date between tbl.date_begin and tbl.date_end
    left outer join tbl as tbl_pre
        on cal.calendar_date between tbl_pre.date_begin and tbl_pre.date_end
        and tbl_pre.ID < tbl.ID
where
    tbl_pre.ID is null
group by 1,2
```

I'm not sure how you're handling counting start/end dates inclusively or not, so can't get more specific.

i.e. if the first record covers 30 days, and the third covers 27, then either Jan 31 or Feb 1 isn't being counted.  But that day is not being counted in your B total.

Comment: The data coming out of this isn't quite right. I'm not sure I understand the tbl_pre.ID < tbl.ID. Since these are letters will this work correctly? Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You'll need some kind of logic in that second join for deciding _which_ id "gets" the range.  I put in a less-than which would just assign the date range to the first ID in dictionary-order.  If you had a priority field you could use that too.